# os.rename PermissionError: [WinError 32]?

Tags: python

I don't know much about os.rename, but in fact it works some most of vedio, but it will post the error when it has only one folder left, the folder's vedios only a few can be renamed, and others can't. What should I do?

```
import os
import cv2
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
import pandas as pd

class FileCheck():

    def get_file_times(self, filename): 
        clip = VideoFileClip(filename)
        file_time = self.timeConvert(clip.duration)
        return file_time

    
    def timeConvert(self, size):  
        M, H = 60, 60 ** 2
        if size < M:
            return str(size) + u's'
        if size < H:
            return u'%s min %s s ' % (int(size / M), int(size % M))
        else:
            hour = int(size / H)
            mine = int(size % H / M)
            second = int(size % H % M)
            tim_srt = u'%s h %s min %s s ' % (hour, mine, second)
            return tim_srt


def get_file_path(root_path, file_list, dir_list,deep):
    
    dir_or_files = os.listdir(root_path)
    for dir_file in dir_or_files:
        
        dir_file_path = os.path.join(root_path, dir_file)
        
        if os.path.isdir(dir_file_path):
          
            dir_list.append(dir_file_path)
            
            get_file_path(dir_file_path, file_list, dir_list,deep+1)
        else:
            if dir_file.find("py")!=-1 :
                continue
            file_list.append(dir_file_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id','time', 'shine'])

    fc = FileCheck()
    
    root_path = r"./"
   
    file_list = []
    
    dir_list = []
    get_file_path(root_path, file_list, dir_list,0)
    #print(file_list)
    s = "YJJ_"

    for i in range(len(file_list)):
        filename = file_list[i]
        print(filename)
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)  
        ftime = fc.get_file_times(filename)  
        df.loc[i] = [s+str(i), ftime, 0]
    print("complete")
    for i in range(len(file_list)):
        filename = file_list[i]
        ss = filename.split("D")[0]
        os.rename(filename, ss + s + str(i)+".mov")

    df.to_csv("result.csv",index=0)
```

I just want to calculate the time of video. But I meet

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'D45.mov' -> 'DJI_0001.mov'
```

Comment: That means what it says -- a file has to be closed to be renamed on Windows (unlike saner, UNIX-y platforms).

Comment: Have you tried closing your `cap` object?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I add the release(), but it doesn't work, it still have this problem, I restart the computer and only run it, most of vedios can be renamed, but a few can't.

Comment: SysInternals has tools to tell you which process has a given file open.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you cannot alter the chosen file because another process is using it, hence doing so might ruin/crash the other process.

Make sure that the file is not open, and is not being used by another program, and try again.

Comment: "corrupt/crash the other process"... if we were still using old FAT-era filesystems without an inode abstraction, _then_ you'd have a very real case for filesystem corruption here. Modern NTFS uses inodes, though, so it just acts like FAT for backwards compatibility (with programs that rely on FAT's semantics for locking), even when there's no real corruption risk.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Okay.

Comment: @Ann Zen I restart the computer and only run it, most of vedios can be renamed, but a few can't.